# Turns me (on) to the fact?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say your discussing about the reason you have chosen a particular hobby. what is the correct *preposition here:*

> 1)...math is superb, and it **turns me on to** the fact that I am lucky that I have a burning passion for this.

Or

> 2)...math is superb, and it **turns me to** the fact that I am lucky that I have a burning passion for this.

P.s:I have just heard the #1 several minutes ago, she was kinda fluent but I am doubtful if this number 1 is grammatical. The #2 example came from mine(I am also in doubt hehe)

Comment: I disagree with that. It turns me onto the fact that. Turns me to the fact is not grammatical/idiomatic.

Comment: @Lambie  I changed my comment to an answer.  I'm not sure if the idiom "turn me to (something)" is ubiquitous, but it doesn't seem that weird to me.

Comment: You both guys have a contradictory answer, I am quite ambivalent right now, really. Which is which then?(this regards to both #1 and #2)

Comment: Relevant note: There's a very similar-sounding idiom "to turn someone on" which means "to sexually arouse someone". Confusing these in public might lead to some serious misunderstandings...

Answer (score 1):

The first is the idiom you want, although, this is not quite how you use *"turn someone on to something"*.  The thing you're *turned on to* doesn't do the *turning on*

> In high school I had a wonderful math teacher who **turned me on** to the subject, so much so that I ended up getting a PhD in applied mathematics.

"Turns X to Y" means "direct X's attention to Y",.  The common usage is in something like a lecture or meeting:

> And so it is resolved that the cafeteria will not serve spaghetti more than two days in a row.  Which **turns us to** the next topic:  desserts.

A related, and probably more common idiom is "*bring* us to X":

> That **brings** us to the next item on the agenda ...

Comment: You both guys have a contradictory answer, I am quite ambivalent right now, really. Which is which then?(this regards to both #1 and #2)

Comment: @JohnArvin  It may be that the idiom "turn me to" is local to a particular dialect.  You can't expect every English speaker to agree about everything. 
 Otherwise both Lambie and I agree that "turn me on to" is the correct idiom for what you are trying to say.